# Rift Wordpress theme, sidebar on single posts not showing

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, sidebar

I have http://spainthephilippines.com/ where I use Rift Theme. Im having problem with showing the sidebar on single post page. On my index page the sidebar is showing, on the 404 page the sidebar is showing. It is working anywhere I use it just not in signle post page. I was looking 2 hours for answer but I cant find it. The theme is on version 1.0, so is it possible that to be the problem? Then why the sidebar shows on most pages? Anyone can help? Tell me if you need any code.

```
<?php global $theme; get_header(); ?>

<div id="main">

    <?php $theme->hook('main_before'); ?>

    <div id="content">

        <?php $theme->hook('content_before'); ?>

        <?php 
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                /**
                 * Find the post formatting for the single post (full post view) in the post-single.php file
                 */
                get_template_part('post', 'single');
            endwhile;

            else :
                get_template_part('post', 'noresults');
            endif; 
        ?>

        <?php $theme->hook('content_after'); ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->

    <?php get_sidebars(); ?>

    <?php $theme->hook('main_after'); ?>

</div><!-- #main -->
```

**EDIT**

Here is the sidebar:

```
<?php global $theme; ?>

<div id="sidebar-primary">

<?php
    if(!dynamic_sidebar('sidebar_primary')) {
        /**
        * The primary sidebar widget area. Manage the widgets from: wp-admin -> Appearance -> Widgets 
        */
        $theme->hook('sidebar_primary');
    }
    $theme->hook("sidebar_primary_after");
?>
```

And also the post-single.php:

```
<?php global $theme; ?>

<div <?php post_class('post post-single clearfix'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <h2 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

    <div class="postmeta-primary">

        <span class="meta_date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
       &nbsp; <span class="meta_categories"><?php the_category(', '); ?></span>

            <?php if(comments_open( get_the_ID() ))  {
                ?> &nbsp; <span class="meta_comments"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'No comments', 'themater' ), __( '1 Comment', 'themater' ), __( '% Comments', 'themater' ) ); ?></span><?php
            }

            if(is_user_logged_in())  {
                ?> &nbsp; <span class="meta_edit"><?php edit_post_link(); ?></span><?php
            } ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="entry clearfix">

        <?php
            if(has_post_thumbnail())  {
                the_post_thumbnail(
                    array($theme->get_option('featured_image_width_single'), $theme->get_option('featured_image_height_single')),
                    array("class" => $theme->get_option('featured_image_position_single') . " featured_image")
                );
            }
        ?>

        <?php
            the_content('');
            wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<p><strong>' . __( 'Pages:', 'themater' ) . '</strong>', 'after' => '</p>' ) );
        ?>


    <?php if(get_the_tags()) {
            ?><div class="postmeta-secondary"><span class="meta_tags"><?php the_tags('', ', ', ''); ?></span></div><?php
        }
    ?> 


<!-- Post ID <?php the_ID(); ?> wtf-->

<?php 
    if(comments_open( get_the_ID() ))  {
        comments_template('', true); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: check your sidebar page I think may be there if(!is_single())

Comment: div structure is not proper please check in inspect element you are close div but there is no opening div

Comment: please add sidebar.php

Comment: Just added the sidebar.php

Comment: I think I removed the </div> that was redundant, still not working.